# ConvertJSONToSQL Json does not have a value for updateKey column

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I am new to apache nifi. I have written a sync flow from  source database to destination database. Both databases are of mysql as of now.

I have tried by setting `Transfer field Names`value to `true` but still got the same error

Flow :

[image]

ConvertJSONToSQL Properties:
[image]

JSON :
[image]

Source table :
[image]

Destination  table:
[image]

EvaluateJsonPath properties
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I know nothing about Apache NiFi but the error message suggests you have a NULL value for FILENAME which is being used as the unique key for generated update statements. Allowing NULLs in a column you intend to use as a unique identifier seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @user1191247 Apache NiFi mostly needs illustration and so images unlike to an ordinary direct DB related question.

Comment: @user1191247 you are correct but if you will see the json , the `FILENAME` column has the value and still getting that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`EvaluateJsonPath`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html), use [`JoltTransformJSON`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) with the following `Jolt Specification`:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "@(value)": "[#1].@(1,name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which will transform the JSON received from [`CaptureChangeMySQL`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cdc-mysql-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.cdc.mysql.processors.CaptureChangeMySQL/) to:

```json
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "FILENAME" : "27filename",
  "object_name" : "date",
  "handback_path" : "abc12300000pleasepleasepphhhhhhhllgodpleasepleasepleasepp.xlsx",
  "rejected_count" : 100000,
  "success_count" : 100,
  "total_rows" : 30,
  "creation_date" : 123456789,
  "status" : "new_status"
} ]
```

This can then be passed on to [`ConvertJSONToSQL`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/). I have tested this and it works. Whether it is the *best* way to do it is another matter.

[image: NiFi Flow]